# BigDecimal - ArithmeticException even with exact representable result

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(8757).divide(new BigDecimal(12));
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

Why is it the case? The result of the division should be 729.75 which has a terminating decimal expansion (.75).

Comment: are you sure that this is the cause? it´s working fine, atleast for me

Comment: Are you **sure** this is the code you're running? It executes perfectly on my machine, returning 729.75.

Comment: Same here. What version of Java are you using. Could you include more details, for example the rest of the code around where you are using this?

Comment: If that helps, the code is executed when running a unit test using Eclipse. The JDK version is 1.8.0_66. That may be a bug...

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was. The code that was actually executed is as follows:

```
public class ClassA {   
    public static final BigDecimal BD2= new BigDecimal(12);
}

public ClassB {
    public static final BigDecimal BD1 = new BigDecimal(8757);
    public static final BigDecimal RESULT = BD1.divide(ClassA.BD2);
}
```

`BD2` was not initialized when the `divide()` method was called (I checked that using a breakpoint). However, I still think there is a bug since it should not throw this exception in this case, which is completely unrelated to what is happening. I guess `BD2` is null when `divide()` is called.